# Can't sent cyrillic text as the parameter of the request

Tags: python-3.x, request, python-unicode

I am trying to send get request with parameters which consist of some cyrillic text. I tried a lot of solutions and get other errors with encoding and decoding. Nothing helps.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import http.client
import json
import urllib.parse

data = {}
data["id"] = 123123
values = {}
values["someText"] = "йцколфыовал фыоварфылова фоывафлова"
data["values"] = values
conn = http.client.HTTPConnection("example.com")
params = {"data": json.dumps(data)}
conn.request("GET", "url_request?{}".format(urllib.parse.urlencode(params)))
res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read()
```

I expect a successfull sending of the request with cyrillic text. 

I got next error message:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd4 in position
>   254: invalid continuation byte "

Thanks.

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to use unicode literals in your source code, but if you insist first decode it to `utf-8`, i.e. `values["someText"] = "йцколфыовал фыоварфылова фоывафлова".decode("utf-8")`

Comment: @zwer I don’t insist. If you see some other ways of sending request with cyrillic text, please tell me.

Comment: I'd advise you to keep your string literals outside of your source code and load them when you need to use/send them. It's typically a bad practice to mix your data and code. Emphasis on _typically_ - there are of course valid reasons to do so...